# Python distributable package - with dynamic excel files

Tags: python, dynamic, packaging

I have an utility tool which takes few excel files (Folder1/File1, Folder2/File2) containing reference data, XML File (Config.xml) containing configuration details  and do some data processing with it.  As the end user needs the flexibility to update the reference data, config file occassionaly. I don't want to include them in the exe when creating the set up for distribution. Python program folder structure is as below:

| Root Folder | Sub Folder |
| --- | --- |
| `a.py` |  |
| `b.py` |  |
| `config.xml` |  |
| `Folder 1` |  |
| `--` | `File1.xlsx` |
| `Folder 2` |  |
| `--` | `File2.xlsx` |

Please help to clarify this if this is possible in python.

Comment: yes, it's possible as long as your exe knows how to find the data files, which you will distribute alongside the exe. what do you use to convert the python script to exe? e.g. for pyinstaller look at https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.